# Scala code runs without compiling using scalac?

Tags: scala

As per the Scala tutorials, we need to compile the Scala code using `scalac filename.scala` before executing it using `scala filename`. But when I tried like `scala filename.scala`, it runs and got the output.

Why is it so? So compiling using scalac is not required to run the code? Could someone please explain this.

Thanks.

---

`scala -help` was really helpful. It says

```
    A file argument will be run as a scala script unless it contains only
    self-contained compilation units (classes and objects) and exactly one
    runnable main method.  In that case the file will be compiled and the
    main method invoked.  This provides a bridge between scripts and standard
    scala source.
```

Thanks Dennis for the pointer.

Comment: Scala can be used as a sort of scripting language and from a newer version on (can't remember which)  , this is possible , running the code without even defining a class or an object

Comment: @DoomProg Interesting. Are you referring to Scala Worksheet when you said "running the code without even defining a class or an object"?

Comment: @crackjack not only. Try making a file with just println("hello") and run it with scala command. If you have scala 2.10 and up I think you should be able to get the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

running the `scala` command actually compiles it first behind the scenes, then runs the resulting program.

Comment: So, as you say, there should be class files generated. These files are used to run. But I couldn't find any class files, generated on current directory. So where should be this class files residing?

Comment: @Maximin in main memory

Comment: @sschaef Thanks. It would be great if I get some links or pointer to docs explaining this. It's interesting, almost all the tutorials I covered missed to quote this.

Comment: @Maximin I don't think it's on memory.  The `ScriptRunner` class calls compiler with the [temp directory path](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ScriptRunner.scala#L95) which is deleted up on JVM exits.  The temp directory path varies for OS.  Also you can save jar file with -save option.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is explained in the help for the `scala` command.

You can get the help by executing the `scala -help` command.